# Differential equation with hyperbolic functions.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

The exercise is to find a differential equation and then solve it using a given hint. After much working, I found the differential equation

$$(a^2 + f^2)(f''-f)=2ff'^{2}$$

Now, using the hint to take $f(x)= a \sinh(v(x))$, I reached another differential equation of the form

$$v'' \cosh(v)= \sinh(v)(v'^{2}+1)$$

Now my main goal is to find $f$ but I have no other hint. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with
$$v'' \cosh(v)= \sinh(v)(v'^{2}+1)$$
This is an ODE of autonomous kind. To solve it the usual change is :
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=w(v)\quad\implies\quad \frac{d^2v}{dx^2}=\frac{dw}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}=w\frac{dw}{dv}=w\:w'$$
$$w\:w' \cosh(v)= \sinh(v)(w^{2}+1)$$
This is a separable ODE.
$$\frac{w\:w'}{w^2+1}=\tanh(v)$$
$$\ln|w^2+1|=2\ln|\cosh(v)|+\text{constant}$$
$$w=\pm\sqrt{c_1\cosh^2(v)-1}=\frac{dv}{dx}$$
$$x(v)=\pm\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{c_1\cosh^2(v)-1}}+\text{constant}$$
This is an elliptic integral. The inverse function $v(x)$ involves a Jacobi elliptic integral, the Jacobi amplitude function.

Some simplification might occur for elementary functions depending on  particular boundary conditions (not given in the wording of the question).